# Switching between resource files at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Windows Forms application, I wish to offer different "window modes" (let's just call them Large and Small, for the sake of simplicity). This means that, with several forms open, I click a button and all forms switch to Small mode (different form layouts, different contents, sizes...). I click another button and they all switch to Large mode.

I plan to do this by creating multiple resource files for every form, each of them containing the settings of one of the modes. I would have "MainForm-Large.resx" and "MainForm-Small.resx", and I thought I could load and apply one or the other with some custom logic.

However, in `InitializeComponent()`, a `ComponentResourceManager` is created, that takes care of loading the resource file. I can derive from it and override the `GetResourceFileName()` method (which apparently would be enough for my needs), however I still can't have it used in the Designer of my form, because the instantiation of the resource manager happens inside the auto-generated code. It is of course not sensible to edit that auto-generated code...

It is also not sensible to forget about the `InitializeComponent()` method and re-apply all the properties in another function of mine. Going through every single control and property is a tedious, non-mechanizable (short of hacking into the Designer processes) task - a task that `InitializeComponent()` performs perfectly instead.

What could I do to re-load and re-apply a resource file ***at runtime***?

Comment: do yourself a favor switch _yourself_ to WPF or UWP for that kind of thing. it would be a lot more simpler and easier. In WinForms you probably have to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I would, but we're releasing in a month :(